# Multiple channels in a single RSS xml - is it ever appropriate?

Tags: xml, rss

A typical xml file for an RSS feed starts with an "rss" element on the outermost level, and usually has a single "channel" element within it that represents the "feed" or "channel." Is there ever a situation where it is appropriate to use multiple channels within an  element, like the following?

```
<rss>
    <channel>
         ...
         <item> ... </item>
    </channel>
    <channel>
         ...
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: The term you were looking for is "element", not "block".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [here](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html):

> Subordinate to the `<rss>` element is a single `<channel>` element, which contains information about the channel (metadata) and its contents.

So there not only is no use case for that – it isn't even allowed.

Comment: That brings about the confusion then - why even have a channel tag in the standard? Why not just add the RSS metadata and contents within the "rss" block? Or am I missing something, conceptually?

Comment: Well, that's because the RSS spec isn't the cleanest out there :) I would recommend using Atom!

Comment: Why have an explicit `<body>` tag in HTML instead of defining everything that isn't in the `<head>` to be in the `<body>`? Several formats have such things :)

Comment: @Joey - The difference being that HTML requires one `head` element and one `body` element. If HTML required one `body` element that all other elements exist inside of, then it would be similarly pointless as the rss required `channel`. Like if it was designed like `<html><stuff><head/><body/></stuff></html>`, there is no clear reason why `<stuff>` is there rather than just having `<head/></body>` at that first level.