# SyndicationFeed object - 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType - Line 2799, position 4

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following error when I execute the application at this line `SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);` :

```
'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType - Line 2799, position 4
```

This is my code :

```
namespace y
{
   public class Database
   {
      public void GetDatas(String url) 
      {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Users\\Lolo\\Desktop\\fluxRSS.xml");  
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {
            String t = item.Title.Text;
            String o = item.Summary.Text;
            String p = item.Content.Type;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The fluxRSS.xml is structured like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Recettes</title>
    <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/recettes.php?action=toutes_les_recettes</link>
    <image>
      <title>Recettes</title>
      <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/recettes.php?action=toutes_les_recettes</link>
      <url>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/medias/clipart/recette_big.png</url>
    </image>
    <description>les dernières recettes déposées</description>
    <item>
      <title>salade marocaine</title>
      <link>http://www.lebruitdufrigo.fr/recette.php?id=275</link>
      <description>la dernière recette de Ben</description>
      <pubDate>Sat, 03 Nov 2012 21:00:42 +0100</pubDate>
    </item>
    //other items
  </channel>
 <channel>
 //other items
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I notice that if I remove all the content of the second and last channel tag, I always have the same error but if I delete completely the second channel tag, I don't have any errors anymore.

Do you have a solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: The example RSS XML is wrong - the first channel closing tag is `channels` and not `channel`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple channels in a single RSS xml - is it ever appropriate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798863/multiple-channels-in-a-single-rss-xml-is-it-ever-appropriate)